# How to check if a parent object exists to avoid undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the below function to decide if I have new value for a key in my json doc or not. If I do, I go and use the new value, otherwise I use the previously stored value. This works fine if it is a direct value I am referencing, but for example if i use

> home_addr.address_line_2 =
> updateValue(oldData.home_address.address_line_2,
> data.home_address_line_2)

and oldData.home_address does not exists it complains that address_line_2 is undefined. So how can I handle this in a way without having to check if each parent object is created to avoid this error ?

```
const updateValue = (oldvalue, newvalue) => {
    if (typeof newvalue !== "undefined" && newvalue !== null) {
        console.log("new Value to trim : " + newvalue)

        if (typeof newvalue == "boolean") {
            return newvalue;  
        } else if(typeof value === 'number') {
            return newvalue; 
        }
        else {
            return newvalue.trim();
        }
     
    } else {
        if (typeof oldvalue !== "undefined" && oldvalue !== null){
        return oldvalue;
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `oldData?.home_address?.address_line_2` will either give undefined, or an address, but not an error.  See [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: when i try home_addr.address_line_1 = updateValue(oldData?.home_address?.address_line_1, data.home_address_line_1)
 i get an error SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: i just read that optional chaining is not supported in nodeJs 13 or lower and i am on 10

Comment: James, if you go and change your remark to an answer i will except it as it is the cleaner way to do this instead of endless if statements. I bit the bullet and went to NodeJS 16 which supports chaining

Answer (score 0):

The check can't be done in the function you are posted, as the error appears before calling it. what you need to do is to either set a default value when saving oldData object, or something like this:

```
if (oldData.hasOwnProperty('home_address'))
  home_addr.address_line_2 = updateValue(oldData.home_address.address_line_2, data.home_address_line_2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what i didn't want to use if statements which bloats the file . The chaning is the way to go , clean and simple